# ERROR: Cannot get property 'compileSdkVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, github, gradle

I am using SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu third party library (github) in my android project. I have imported ResideMenu project to my workspace and 
made it as a module dependency library project.

While build the project I got the following error:

> ```
> Error:(7) A problem occurred evaluating project ':ResideMenu'.
> Cannot get property 'compileSdkVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist
> ```

[image: android studio log error]

Comment: you can get rid of this error by copying the value of compileSdkVersion in the app level build.gradle and pasting it in the compileSdkVersion of your library

Answer (score 5):

If you explain more I can help better but most probably problem is in your gradle. You need to say that you have extension file to top-level gradle. Let me explain how it works:

In your app-level gradle file, there should be configuration like that:

```
def config = rootProject.extensions.getByName("ext")
```

You can use configurations from extension file like that:

```
android { 
  compileSdkVersion config.getAt("compileSdkVersion") 
}
```

But, you need to add extension file to your root of project:

**dependency-versions.gradle**

```
ext {
compileSdkVersion = 25
//...
}
```

and you need to say it to your top-level gradle like that:

```
def config = rootProject.extensions.getByName("ext")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add add `AndroidResideMenu` dependency in your `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.0'  //add like this
 }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 19
    buildToolsVersion = "20.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this? I'm getting this error on a CI machine, but it doesn't seem to occur on anyone's local machines. I'm not sure why it would be necessary to add it as a dependency on your buildscript